# Why doesn't my bit-counting function work for negative numbers? (Python)

Tags: python, binary, bitwise-operators

I'm [trying to implement](http://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/bit-count) a function that counts the 1's in the binary representation of an integer. Why does it not work for negative integers?

```
def bit_count(n):
    bits = 0
    while n != 0:
        bits += (n&1)
        n = n >> 1
    return bits
```

I've done some investigation and found that using bin(n) and counting 1's in the resulting string would work instead, but I'd like to find out why this version isn't working.

Thank you!

*edit:* to clarify, it solves for large + integers instantly, but runs indefinitely for any - integer.

**Follow-up question:** is this task impossible in Python, given its representation of negative numbers?

**Resolution:** to fix the problem, I used a counter so that the while loop ran a maximum of 32 times, i.e. getting the 32-bit representation of the negative numbers. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified. It resolves instantly for large positive numbers up to dozens of bits long, but for a negative number as small as -1 it drags on forever.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement `-1` is represented as a sequence of `1`s. Using python's int type, `-1>>1`==`-1` so your loop never exits. `bin(n)` is misleading for negative numbers.

Comment: Oh, I wouldn't have thought the sequence of 1's would be infinite. Is this task impossible in Python, then? Thank you both for your comments.

Comment: it isn't infinite - but your loop wont end as n never gets to zero.

Comment: Why exactly does -1>>1 == -1?

Comment: The implementation of python integers is such that values >=0 appear to have an infinite sequence of 0 bits at the top, and values <0 appear to have infinite sequence of 1 bits. So -1 is the same as ~0, just an infinite sequence of 1's, which is not changed by >>1. In the actual implementation[`*`], the number is stored as its absolute value (using as much storage as needed) plus a sign, but the shift and bitwise ops emulate the infinite view. [`*`] this is true for Python 3.x int and Python 2.x 'long'; ints behave the same way since 2.6 or so, converting to long when needed.

Comment: You can also do `n &= 0xFFFFFFFF` at the start of your function, which converts any negative numbers to positive numbers which are the same in the lower 32 bits.

Comment: A better solution that doesn't needlessly restrict the inputs to 32-bit is to just do "n = abs (n)" on function entry.

Comment: Is there anything equivalent of converting a negatove number to unsigned int as in C/C++? Also what if somebody wants to count set bits in 2's complement?

Comment: @piepi you might want to ask this as a new question.